# What is HTTP Parser, where it is used, what does it do

Tags: c, http, parsing, github, open-source

I was reading C code at:- https://github.com/joyent/http-parser
. But I don't know what is the meaning of the HTTP Parser . Can you please explain its meaning probably  with example so I can contribute to this project.

Comment: If you don't know what it does, why do you want to contribute to it?

Comment: HTTP is a (primarily) text based (i.e. - human readable) protocol.  As such a computer program needs to interpret the text according to HTTP's syntax to extract its meaning.  That is what an http parser does.

Comment: If you read the description and if you search a bit about what those words mean you will get the answer.. And this is not SO related questions IMO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTTP Parser can be employed in the browser as well as in the server and it  extracts the following information from HTTP messages:

1 Header fields and values

2 Content-Length

3 Request method

4 Response status code

5 Transfer-Encoding

6 HTTP version

7 Request URL

8 Message body

Answer (score 5):

I think the README.md already explained it very well:

https://github.com/joyent/http-parser/blob/master/README.md